# Blender file imported to unity has different scalings on each axis

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender

I'm trying to import a blender file into Unity, and it looks right. But the scaling of the object in unity is weird. In blender I set it to (1, 1, 1), but Unity imports it as (50, 26, 13). This wouldn't be a problem, if this scaling wouldn't lead to some weird deformities when I rotate the part with a JointHinge. I tried exporting the blender model as fbx or just importing it as a blender file into unity. I also tried different fbx export settings, which didn't help.
Anyone encountered this before?

Blender version of the model:

[image: Blender version of the model] (Scaling 1, 1, 1)

Unity version of the model:

[image: Unity version of the model]   (Scaling 50, 26, 13 but looks the same)

Comment: As I wrote in my question above, I tried that and it didn't work either

Comment: What FBX settings did you use?

Comment: Any chance you could share the `.blend` file somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Import Settings. Select the .blend file in Unity-Explorer and look in the Inspector. Maybe some setting is wrong.

Also try to apply the scaling in blender. [CTRL]+[A] -> [Scale] on windows. However, you screenshot looks like it's already (1,1,1) in Blender.